# Trying to understand strange string concatenation behavior

Tags: c#, string, debugging, char, concatenation

I have a very simple method that takes a string, breaks it into a char array, then creates a new string from the pieces. However it is performing unexpectedly and I don't understand why? Here is a picture of breakpoint. The input string in this case is "20160622".

Edit: Sorry for the pic. Here is the question in text.

```
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            string test = "20160622";
            Console.WriteLine(ConvertDateField(test));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static string ConvertDateField(string date)
        {
            var temp = date.ToCharArray();
            var output = temp[0] + temp[1] + temp[2] + temp[3] + "-" + temp[4] + temp[5] + "-" + temp[6] + temp[7] + " 00:00:00";

            return output;
        }
    }
```

The output is "201-06-22 00:00:00".

Edit 2: I understand there are probably better ways to do this. What I am trying to understand is why this code is functioning the way it is. ie. why is the 6 the only char not being concatenated?

[image]

As you can see, the fourth char, temp[3] which is a '6', is not being concatenated into the output string. Why?

Edit 3: I solved the problem this way

```
    private static string ConvertDateField(string date)
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00");
    }
```

Thank you Steve for your advice.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with the code and output as *text* rather than as a screenshot. Fundamentally though, it sounds like you should probably be parsing the value and reformatting it.

Comment: Seems like a really weird and bad way to format a date. Use DateTime.TryParse with the format string to parse the date into a DateTime object and then use the ToString() with a format string to output it how you want.

Comment: whats with all the down votes. I don't get it. I couldn't figure out the problem without actually trying it in a debugger. Needless to say for beginners.

Comment: I suspect the downvotes have to do with the way the question is asked (an image instead of code, etc.) rather than with the question itself.

Comment: At first glance, you've only given a screenshot, and it doesn't appear to be the amount of information normally needed for folks to answer these sorts of questions. But given the upvoted answer, the function code you display, with the given input was enough. It would be better if you included the code as text (in a code block) so people can quickly try out your code themselves.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have added sample code to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your question. The char concat is not a string concat. What happened is that c# is doing Math operation for the chars by casting them to int with ASCII.

The corresponding ascii for temp 1, 2, 3, 4 are 50, 48, 49, 54 which the sum is 201. (what a coincidence)

and then `int + string` concat resulted in string so the rest of the string worked as expected.

There is an easier way to perform the convert if it was a DateTime object. You can simply call `dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00")` and you will get the result you want.

Comment: Good catch, and what a misleading coincidence.